# Nested SP to return table data

Tags: mysql

I want to return some ids from stored procedure, which would be used in "in Clause-Mysql".

Ex.

```
create procedure getid
as
begin
select empid from table 
end;
create procedure getdata
As
begin 
select * from employees where empid in (call getid(3))
end;
```

the above sample is simple scenario, but i want to implement a complicated query ,so i cannot join in getdata storedprocedure. simply i want to use nested sp which returns table of data should be used in in clause.

Answer (score 0):

Although a mysql procedure can return a resultset (**not** a table), you cannot use it as a table in another query or stored procedure. Mysql functions cannot return table either.

You either have to use a [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) instead of a stored procedure or the stored procedures must use the same temporary table to pass data to each other.